# Как обновить запись в процедуре с параметром %ROWTYPE?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Как обновить запись в процедуре с параметром %ROWTYPE?

```
PROCEDURE p_update (
    p_id     IN   t.id%TYPE,
    p_row    IN   t%rowtype) IS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t SET row = p_row
    WHERE id = p_id; 
END p_update;

declare 
    t_row   t%rowtype;
    t_id    t.id%type;
begin
    t_row.name := 'TEST';
    t_id := 10;
    pck_api.p_update(t_row, t_id);
end;
```

Получаю ошибку:

> PLS-00306 wrong number or types of arguments

---

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to execute UPDATE stored procedure with %ROWTYPE](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61587839) от участника [Pavlos04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13436990/pavlos04)</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/61587839

Answer (score 2):

Причина ошибки - параметры перепутаны местами. Но это ещё не всё, все атрибуты переменной с типом `%ROWTYPE` изначально `NULL`, включая соответствующие столбцы таблицы с ограничением `NOT NULL`. Их надо инициализировать до обновления.

Вот пример, как это надо сделать:

```
create table t (id int, name varchar2 (8), dt date not null)
/
insert into t values (10, 'aaa', date'2020-08-27');

create or replace package pck_api as 
    function  gett (id t.id%type) return t%rowtype;
    procedure updt (id t.id%type, trow t%rowtype);
end;
/    
create or replace package body pck_api as 
    function  gett (id t.id%type) return t%rowtype is
        ret t%rowtype;
    begin
        select * into ret 
        from t where id = gett.id for update;
        return ret;
    end; 
    procedure updt (id t.id%type, trow t%rowtype) is
    begin
        update t set row = trow where id = updt.id; 
    end;
end;
/
```

Так использовать:

```
var rc refcursor
declare 
    trow t%rowtype;
    id t.id%type := 10;
begin
    trow := pck_api.gett (id);
    trow.name := 'bbb';
    trow.dt := date'2020-08-28';
    pck_api.updt(id, trow);
    open :rc for select * from t;
end;
/

        ID NAME     DT                 
---------- -------- -------------------
        10 bbb      2020-08-28 00:00:00
```